# Adding titles to flextables in a list of lists

Tags: r, list, flextable

I thought this would be super easy, but I am doing something wrong nonetheless.

## Example data

I have example data as follows (which is a list of lists of flextables):

```
library(data.table)
library(flextable)
datA <- fread("anyvar somevar
               2  4
               2  3
               2  5")

dat_list <- list("one" = list("datA" = datA, "datB" = 2*datA),"two" = list("datC" = 3*datA, "datD" = 4*datA), "three" = list("datE" = 5*datA, "datF" = 6*datA))

for (i in seq_along(dat_list) ) {
  for (j in seq_along( dat_list[[i]] ) ) {
    dat_list[[i]][[j]] <- flextable( dat_list[[i]][[j]] )
  }
}

vector_of_lists <- c("one", "two", "three")
```

## Attempt

I simply want to add titles to each flextable `one`, `two`, `three`.

```
for (i in seq_along(dat_list) ) {
  for (j in seq_along( dat_list[[i]] ) ) {
    dat_list[[i]][[j]] <- add_header_row(dat_list[[i]][[j]],  top = TRUE, values = paste0("Table: ", i, " Header of table", vector_of_lists[i] ))
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in inverse.rle(structure(list(lengths = colwidths, values = values),  : 
  invalid 'rle' structure
```

## Desired output:

Something like below, but then with: `Table 1: Header of table one`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the code from `add_header_row()` to `set_caption()` works

```r
for (i in seq_along(dat_list) ) {
  for (j in seq_along( dat_list[[i]] ) ) {
    dat_list[[i]][[j]] <- set_caption(dat_list[[i]][[j]], caption = paste0("Table: ", i, " Header of table", vector_of_lists[i] ))
  }
}

dat_list[[3L]][[1L]]
```

[image: HTML table of caption added to R flextable]

The issue was that `add_header_rows()` generally wants the user to include a named character vector that matches the column names that you want additional header information for. To at least get your original approach from not erroring, you could have specified that the `colwidths = 2` where 2 is the number of columns of your table.

```r
 for (i in seq_along(dat_list) ) {
   for (j in seq_along( dat_list[[i]] ) ) {
     dat_list[[i]][[j]] <- add_header_row(dat_list[[i]][[j]], top = TRUE,colwidths = 2,values = paste0("Table: ",i," Header of table",vector_of_lists[i] ))
   }
 }

dat_list[[3L]][[1L]]
```

The styling is slightly different as now we have two rows of headers instead of a header and a title.

[image: HTML table header row inserted for R flextable]